# Maven: how to know where is local repository (localRepository/M2_REPO) in an efficient way?

Tags: maven

For a build integration between maven based projects and the rest of world, I need to be able to find out where Maven thinks the local repository for the current user/build is, but from outside Maven.

For now, I use:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="localRepository" | grep basedir | sed -e "s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/")
```

This works (or seems to work in the subsets of cases I met), but it is *extremelly* slow: each call to that line takes a couple of seconds (starting the JVM, letting maven do what it needs, etc). It is unberable in an interactive build.

So, does anybody know if there is a quicker way to find that?
I believe I can't just look for the M2_REPO environment variable, as the value can be defined elsewhere (in user settings.xml? And elsewhere?)

My better idea for now is to set an envirnment-variable with the key builtd based on the project path to at least limit the evaluation slow-down to one time.

Any ideas or insigh would be very helpfull.

Comment: The question is why do you need the location of the local cache? I would assume you only need the results of maven build `jar, war, ear. etc.`...

Comment: BTW: Why not simply: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -v "^\[INFO\]"`

Comment: @khmarbaise: I need the local cache to know if an other lib was already built or need to be (in the context of  multi-stage build in CI where the artifact are not cheap to build)
It's the same reason for my regex in grep: I need to actually have the path to use it as an input for other scripts.

Comment: If you are on Jenkins Pipelines you can use stash file / unstash file so you don't need to go via the local cache...furthermore it sounds you like to synchronize via the existence of a file (build by something else)...

Answer (score 0):

The local repository can be found in `.m2/repository` in the user directory unless it is specified otherwise in the `settings.xml`.

Parse the `settings.xml`.

Comment: It can at least also be specified via environment variable. So I need to know exactly what are all the source from which the variable can be set. Then, I need to know the overrides rules implemented in Maven (I didn't found any documentation on that). Then, I need to find the source itself (where is setting.xml? Its path can be defined multiple way to override default). It's a lot brittle work to do...